# How to add UIView inside a UITableViewCell Programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have been creating an app which has a View as that of **AppStore (iOS 11) - {Today}** view.

Just want to know how do I approach that view. Yet, I think the approach is to create a UIViewController with extensions of UITableViewDataSource and -Delegate, I can get the number of rows and data in my ViewController. And In the dequeReusableCell, I have created a UITableViewCell class in which I have created a UIView Programmatically but that's not working.

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

let cellView:UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    view.layer.cornerRadius = 15
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
    view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 5
    return view
}()
}
```

In the above class snippet, there is no way to insert my UIView in the main view.

There is no method to add views(obviously) because it's under UIViewController rather than UITableViewCell.
So my question is how do I get UIView inside a tableViewCell

**Or Is there any other approach to get exact view cells as ios 11 Today tab view?** This is what I want ->

***I have upgraded my Question, please have a look [here]***[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52202237/how-to-nest-a-uicollectionviewcell-inside-another-one): [How to nest a UICollectionViewCell inside another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52202237/how-to-nest-a-uicollectionviewcell-inside-another-one)

[image]

Comment: override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        contentView.addSubview(cellView)
    }
insert method in tableviewcell class

Answer (score 4):

You can add customView to uitableviewcell like this.

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    let cellView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        view.layer.cornerRadius  = 15
        view.backgroundColor     = UIColor.white
        view.layer.shadowColor   = UIColor.black.cgColor
        view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        view.layer.shadowOffset  = CGSize.zero
        view.layer.shadowRadius  = 5
        return view
    }()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        addSubview(cellView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer buddy. I have upgraded my question. Can you have a look here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52202237/how-to-nest-a-uicollectionviewcell-inside-another-one]

Comment: What if I want to add to a new cell instead of a coordinate? if I do something like this it is set in a specific frame of the window.
var customViewCell: MyTableViewCell()
func viewDidLoad() { 
        super.viewDidLoad()
        customViewCell.awakeFromNib()
}

Answer (score 2):

> have a look at this git project this will help you :)

https://github.com/phillfarrugia/appstore-clone

Comment: Wow, I just got to know that UICollectionViewCell is used as cards instead of UITableViewCell. Thanks for that.

Comment: I have upgraded my Question, can you answer this: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52202237/how-to-nest-a-uicollectionviewcell-inside-another-one)