# How to nest a UICollectionViewCell inside another one?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Following my old question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52201273/how-to-add-uiview-inside-a-uitableviewcell-programmatically): [How to add UIView inside a UITableViewCell Programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52201273/how-to-add-uiview-inside-a-uitableviewcell-programmatically)

I wanna achieve an enhanced view like that of iOS 11 Today tab with adding more elements in those collectionViewCell cards.

I want to add **biDirectional Scrolling like that of Netflix or other AppStore tabs**(Games & Apps) inside my CollectionViewCell card(App Store Today tab cells). Here is an overview of what I want: 
[image]

Please tell is it possible to achieve such thing. If yes then how?
Thanks.

Comment: Create a vertical CollectionView. The corresponding CollectionViewCell should be custom views that inherit from `UICollectionView`. Use the custom views as your films container. That'd be it. Work on it and post a question back if you face trouble, but don't expect someone to write all the code for you without having tried first.

Comment: You can use `UITableView` for vertical scroll with `UITableViewSection` and `UITableViewCell`. And `UITableViewCell` with `UICollectionView` and its `UICollectionViewCell`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Obviously, I just wanna know the approach, I'm not asking for the code. I know ethics. Anyway Thanks! @regina_fallangi

Comment: Please avoid taking commendations personally. Plenty of people, when new, don't know that one first has to try in SO. Writing speech can sound harsher than meant.

Comment: @PratikSodha Man you are confusing me. I came up to this question after clearing my doubts on this(My old quesiton) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52201273/how-to-add-uiview-inside-a-uitableviewcell-programmatically]

Comment: @regina_fallangi I have done what you suggested, and here I ran into another problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52274801/how-to-show-view-controller-on-selecting-row-cell-of-tableviewas-a-collection-v

Answer (score -1):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ObjCell: UICollectionViewCell{

let leftView: UIView = {
    let view: UIView = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
view.frame = CGRect(x:20, y:50, width:320, height:50)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setCellUI()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setCellUI(){

    backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    addSubview(leftView) 
}
}
```

Comment: You should add some explanation to your code always. It's bad to just give a snippet.

Comment: Bro this is  a CollectionViewCell Class here you can see how to add UIView programmatically....?