# How to show view controller on selecting row cell of tableView(as a collection view cell)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I have the Main View Controller which has a collection view with its collection view cells each initialized as a tableView to serve multiple rows inside of that collection view cell. **If you're getting confused, below is the snapshot of the current state.**

***The problem is when I try to tap a tableView row cell to open another view controller, It fails and a selected state of table view cell is shown.***

Here is the snapshot.[image]

```
//HomeCollectionViewCell.swift
class HomeCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    setUpCellView()
}
func setUpCellView() {
    let frame = CGRect(x:20, y:20, width: bounds.width - 40, height: 600)
    let cell = CellView(frame: frame)
    contentView.addSubview(cell)
  }
}

//CellView.swift
class CellView: UITableView {
    let quoteCell = "QuoteCell"
    let newsCell = "NewsCell"
    let articleCell = "ArticleCell"
    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: .grouped)
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        self.backgroundColor = .white
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self
        self.register(QuoteTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: quoteCell)
        self.register(NewsTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: newsCell)
        self.register(ArticleTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: articleCell)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
extension CellView: UITableViewDelegate {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch indexPath.section {
        case 0: return 35
        case 1: return 140
        case 2: return 100
        case 3: return 140
        default: return 0
    }
  }
}
extension CellView: UITableViewDataSource {
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return categories.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return categories[section]
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.section {
        case 0: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: dateCell)
                cell?.textLabel?.text = "Today"
                cell?.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30, weight: UIFont.Weight.heavy)

        return cell!
        case 1: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: quoteCell) as! QuoteTableViewCell
        return cell
        case 2: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: newsCell) as! NewsTableViewCell
        return cell
        case 3: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: articleCell) as! ArticleTableViewCell
        return cell
        default: let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: commonCell)
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "LOL"
        return cell!
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0: print("Date Selected")
    case 1: print("Quote Selected")
    case 2: print("News Selected")
    case 3: let homeViewController = HomeViewController()
            let articleDetailViewController = ArticleDetailViewController()
//homeViewController.show(articleDetailViewController, sender: homeViewController)//homeViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(articleDetailViewController, animated: true)
    homeViewController.present(articleDetailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("Article selected")
    default: print("LOL")
    }
  }   
}
```

//HomeViewController.swift

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupNavBar()
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    setUpConstraints()
    configure(collectionView: collectionView)
}
func setUpConstraints() {
    _ = collectionView.anchor(view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 10, leftConstant: 10, bottomConstant: 10, rightConstant: 10, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)
    collectionView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
}

lazy var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    cv.clipsToBounds = true
    cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    cv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    cv.backgroundColor = .clear
    cv.isHidden = false
    return cv
}()
}
private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"
extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
internal func configure(collectionView: UICollectionView) {
    collectionView.register(HomeCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 0)
}
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 7
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 600)
}
}
```

Please tell where I'm doing wrong or What approach should I use?

Note- No use of storyboards/IB. Done things programmatically only.

Comment: Use delegate pattern and forward the tap from the cell to the main view controller and present your detail view controller from there

Comment: @MichałKwiecień Can you please elaborate and give a little snippet of code for delegate

Answer (score 0):

Give identifiers("**HomeViewController**" and "**ArticleDetailViewController**") to view controllers and try below code in *didSelectRow()*.

```
case 3:
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let sourceViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as? HomeViewController
let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ArticleDetailViewController") as? ArticleDetailViewController
let navigator: UINavigationController = sourceViewController as! UINavigationController                                                                                                                                                       
navigator.pushViewController(destinationViewController!, animated: true)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing, I didn't use storyboards and IB in the whole project, all done programmatically. I don't think so if it may work.

Comment: Your snippet won't work. I tried the above code it fails as I don't use storyboards. Moreover, on initializing the navigator line, I get this warning - "Cast from 'HomeViewController?' to unrelated type 'UINavigationController' always fails"

Comment: Did you try **self.navigationController?.present(articleDetailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)** ?

Comment: self.navigationController - not possible because navigation and such properties are of ViewController and not UIView or UITableViews.

Answer (score 0):

From what have you done, I want to point out that its not a good idea to present `UIViewController` from `UView`. You must write some custom delegates which will get fired once someone taps on those cells in the custom `CellView` class. Those delegates must be implemented in the view controller that contains the tableview. From the `UIViewController` you must write the code to present the new viewcontrollers.